# Tika throwing AttributeError through python on windows

Tags: python, windows, pdf, apache-tika

```
pdf=parser.from_file("Sample.pdf")
print(pdf['content'])
```

I am trying to use the Tika module for python to read a pdf file (above code) however the following error is thrown:
***AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'setsid'*** 
From my understanding setsid is only available in unix and I am on windows. Does this mean i cannot use tika or is there a way around this?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.7.4

Comment: Can you upgrade your Tika Python version? [Looks like this bug has recently been fixed](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python/issues/278)